# Move-Item: Illegal characters in path - filename with spaces

Tags: powershell

I have an issue with moving a file that contains spaces.

`This is the example path: $transfer.FileName = D:\this\is\a\file with a lot of spaces.xml`

```
$file = $transfer.FileName
Move-Item -path $file -Destination $archiveFolder
```

Error:

```
Move-Item : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:17
+                 Move-Item -path $file -Destination $archiveFolder
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\this\i...ong 2022-08.xml:FileInfo) [Move-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

When i run `test-path $file` I receive `$true`. I have tried replacing the spaces with "` " but after that i got a new error saying that the path was not correct.

Does someone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try `Move-Item -LiteralPath $file -Destination $archiveFolder`

Comment: While using `-LiteralPath` with paths known to be literal paths is always recommended, the problem in this case is with the `$archiveFolder` (`-Destination`) argument, which is invariably treated as a literal path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your problem** isn't with the input file, `$file`, but with the ***destination* path, `$archiveFolder`**:

The error message implies that **`$archiveFolder` contains characters that are illegal in a file-system path**, namely (on Windows) `* ?  < > |` and, except as part of a drive spec such as `C:`, `:`.

Note that [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item)'s `-Destination` parameter does *not* support [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expressions.

Therefore:

- If the value is meant to be a *literal* path, remove the illegal character and try again.
- If the value is a *wildcard* expression, resolve it to a literal path first, and ensure that it resolves to just *one* literal path:

  ```
  # Resolve the presumed wildcard pattern in $archiveFolder
  # to a full, literal path.
  $archiveFolderLiteral = Resolve-Path $archiveFolder
  if ($archiveFolderLiteral.Count -ne 1) { 
    throw "Wildcard expression `"$archiveFolder`" did not resolve to a single, literal path."
  }

  # Also note the use of -LiteralPath instead of -Path - see below.
  Move-Item -LiteralPath $file -Destination $archiveFolderLiteral
  ```

---

As for the *input* path:

As long as you *quote* a path that contains spaces (or other metacharacters) (e.g. 
`'D:\this\is\a\file with a lot of spaces.xml'`),<sup>[1]</sup> it is correctly passed as a single argument to the target command.

However, there's an additional consideration with respect to file-processing cmdlets:

- Their `-Path` parameter (which is also the default parameter if you pass a path *positionally* as the first argument) expects *wildcard* expressions, which means that a path that contains `[` and `]` that is meant to be a *literal* path gets *misinterpreted*.
- Thus, for full robustness, it is **best to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter explicitly whenever your paths are *literal* ones** rather than wildcards.

---

<sup>[1] When passing paths directly as arguments (as opposed to storing them in a variable with `$path = ...` first), you may alternatively escape individual metacharacters with `` ` ``, though with multiple spaces, for instance, that becomes cumbersome; e.g., to pass verbatim `test file 1`: `` Write-Output test` file` 1 ``</sup>

Comment: Hi! My problem was indeed that $archiveFolder was a path with a wildcard at the end. I didn't need to use the wildcard there, so I removed it. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear the issue is resolved, @BeckaPecka; my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate your issue.

```
$filename = "D:\Desktop\New folder\New Text Document.txt"
$archiveFolder = "D:\Desktop\New folder\temp"
Move-Item -path $filename -Destination $archiveFolder
```

No error returned and the file was moved.
Are you enclosing the filename with double quotes?

Comment: This isn't really an answer and should be posted as a comment instead. I know that you cannot comment yet due to having fewer than 50 reputation points, but you're very close. As an aside: if the problem were lack of quoting of the input file path, the error message would be different.

Comment: @mklement0 Yes it was more like a comment. By the way, your answer is the same as the comment in the question. That comment should have be an answer as well.

Comment: Do you mean Mathias' comment _on_ the question, with respect to `-LiteralPath`? My answer mentions that _as an aside_ in its bottom section (and, for added robustness, incorporates it into the code shown), because it is _incidental_ to the solution. The cause of the OP's issue is explained in the top section, which is mentioned nowhere else.

Comment: It's implied by my previous comment, but just to spell it out: The command from the comment, `Move-Item -LiteralPath $file -Destination $archiveFolder`, does _not_ solve the problem. As for comments vs. answers: Once you have the commenting privilege and you see a comment that you believe should be converted into an answer, you can @-address the commenter in a comment encouraging them to do so. Something that should be a comment getting posted an answer is a - prominent - distraction. Something that should be an answer getting posted as a comment is a missed opportunity. Both should be avoided